# Min-cost-max-flow with extra flow constraint

Tags: algorithm, network-flow

I'm trying to solve a min-cost-max-flow problem with extra flow constraints. It seems classic network flow algorithms cannot handle this problem.

**Here is an example:**

Saying I have a bipartite graph, and each edge between left and right has a cost. Different from classic min-cost-max-flow problem, the allowed flow of each edge can either be (0 or 1), or (0 or 2) in my problem. Like the figure ([example flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXGKT.jpg)) shows (I didn't draw source and target). Note that for the edges with allowed flow of (0 or 2), flow == 1 is not allowed.

I don't expect to get optimal solution, but need to solve it in polynomial time.

I would really appreciate any suggestions/help.

Thank you!

Comment: For (0 or 1) case you can simply solve it with setting capacity of edges as 1 and running the trivial MCMF algo. isn't it? Only figuring out is req. for (0 or 2) case. Right?

Comment: Where are the sources and sinks?  As it stands, flow balance at each vertex implies all flows must be 0.

Comment: @adisticated Right. If all edges are (0 or 1), then MCMF can solve it easily. But the (0 or 2) is a headache, since the feasible set is not convex anymore.

Comment: @j_random_hacker There should be a source on the left and a sink on the right, and we push non-zero flow from source to sink. I just didn't draw it.

Comment: What are the capacities on the edges from the source, and to the sink?  If they're infinite, then set the flows on all edges crossing the bipartition to their capacities (either 1 or 2) and you're done.  IOW: this problem is *still* incompletely specified.